# Graph $|z+2-i|=2$

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to graph the complex equation $|z+2-i|=2$
However I have no idea how to proceed. I'm also unsure of what to do with the modulus.
How is this supposed to look?

Comment: use a dollar sign around stuff instead of <math> and </math>

Comment: Think of it as the distance/length between $z$ and $i-2$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $|z-z_0|=2$ iff the distance from $z$ to $z_0$ is $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z = x+yi$, then

$$\begin{align*}
|x+yi + 2 - i| &= 2\\
\sqrt{(x+2)^2 + (y-1)^2} &= 2\\
(x+2)^2 + (y-1)^2 &= 2^2
\end{align*}$$

which becomes the formula of a circle on the $xy$-plane.